# How do I get instant validation of form fields in this React 18 app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I am working on a chat app with React 18 and Firebase.

In the `src\pages\Register.jsx` component, I have a form that I validate with **[Simple Body Validator](https://github.com/jadKhoury1/simple-body-validator)**:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FormCard from '../components/FormCard/FormCard';
import { make } from 'simple-body-validator';

export default function Register() {
 const initialFormData = {
    firstName: '',
    lastName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    passwordConfirm: ''
 };

 const validationRules = {
    firstName: ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
    lastName: ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
    email: ['required', 'email'],
    password: ['required', 'confirmed'],
    passwordConfirm: ['required'],
 };

 const validator = make(initialFormData, validationRules);
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialFormData);
 const [errors, setErrors] = useState(validator.errors());

 const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, [name]: value }));
  };

 const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    if (!validator.setData(formData).validate()) {
      setErrors(validator.errors());
    }
 };
  
 return (
    <FormCard title="Register">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has('firstName') ? 'has-error' : null}`}>
          <label for="firstName" className="form-label">First name</label>
          <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" value={formData.firstName} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control form-control-sm" />
          { errors.has('firstName') ? (
          <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first('firstName')}</p>
        ) : null }
        </div>

        <div className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has('lastName') ? 'has-error' : null}`}>
          <label for="lastName" className="form-label">Last name</label>
          <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" value={formData.lastName} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control form-control-sm" />
          { errors.has('lastName') ? (
          <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first('lastName')}</p>
        ) : null }
        </div>

        <div className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has('email') ? 'has-error' : null}`}>
          <label for="email" className="form-label">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value={formData.email} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control form-control-sm" />
          { errors.has('email') ? (
          <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first('email')}</p>
        ) : null }
        </div>

        <div className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has('password') ? 'has-error' : null}`}>
          <label for="password" className="form-label">Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value={formData.password} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control form-control form-control-sm" />
          { errors.has('password') ? (
          <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first('password')}</p>
        ) : null }
        </div>

        <div className={`mb-2 form-element ${errors.has('passwordConfirm') ? 'has-error' : null}`}>
          <label for="password_repeat" className="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
          <input type="password" id="passwordConfirm" name="passwordConfirm" value={formData.passwordConfirm} onChange={handleChange} className="form-control form-control form-control-sm" />
          { errors.has('passwordConfirm') ? (
          <p className="invalid-feedback">{errors.first('passwordConfirm')}</p>
        ) : null }
        </div>

        <div className="pt-1">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-sm btn-success fw-bold">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </FormCard>
  );
 }
```

If the form is invalid, once a submit is adempted, the validation error messages are displayed as expected:

[image]

#### The problem

If valid data is introduced into an invalid form, the validation error messages and classes do not disappear on input/change, as I believe it should.

The valid fields *pass the validation only upon a new click of the submit button* while I want the feedback to be *instant*, similar to the AngularJS or Angular2+ forms.

#### Sandbox

There is a sandbox with the code **[here](https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-cloud-wmf2jn)**. The registration route is `/auth/register`.

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What is the most reliable way to get the desired behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed that the library you're using does not handle form states(e.g. dirty, pristine).

So, here would be my approach:

#### Register.tsx

```js
/* ... */
const initialFormData = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  email: "",
  password: "",
  passwordConfirm: ""
};

const [pristineFields, setPristineFields] = useState(() =>
  Object.keys(initialFormData)
);

const handleChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;

  setFormData((prevFormData) => {
    const newFormData = { ...prevFormData, [name]: value };
    const newPristineFields = pristineFields.filter((f) => f !== name);

    validator.setData(newFormData).validate();
    const validationErrors = validator.errors();
    // 'Forgetting' about pristine fields.
    newPristineFields.forEach((f) => validationErrors.forget(f));
    setErrors(validationErrors);

    setPristineFields(newPristineFields);

    return newFormData;
  });
};

/* ... */
```

I have also added these lines in the `submit` handler:

```js
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (!validator.setData(formData).validate()) {
    setErrors(validator.errors());
  } else {
    console.log("all good");
  }

  // Validations are shown either way, so we could forget
  // about any pristine fields at this point.
  setPristineFields([]);
};
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-parm-h52ync?file=/src/pages/Register.jsx) is the link to the updated CodeSandbox application.

---

### Update - validating/invalidating confirm password

```
const CONFIRM_PASSWORD_KEY = "passwordConfirm";
const PASSWORD_KEY = "password";

export default function Register() {
  const initialFormData = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    email: "",
    [PASSWORD_KEY]: "",
    [CONFIRM_PASSWORD_KEY]: ""
  };
...
```

Then, in the `setFormData`'s callback, I have added the logic for password confirmation:

```
...
    setFormData((prevFormData) => {
      const newFormData = { ...prevFormData, [name]: value };
      const newPristineFields = pristineFields.filter((f) => f !== name);

      validator.setData(newFormData).validate();
      const validationErrors = validator.errors();
      newPristineFields.forEach((f) => validationErrors.forget(f));

      // Other cases can be handled here..
      if (name === CONFIRM_PASSWORD_KEY) {
        if (value !== newFormData[PASSWORD_KEY]) {
          validationErrors.add(CONFIRM_PASSWORD_KEY, {
            message: "Passwords do not match."
          });
        }
      }

      setErrors(validationErrors);
      setPristineFields(newPristineFields);
      return newFormData;
    });
...
```

Comment: It seems to work fine, _except_ for (in)validating password confirmation.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir what do you mean by _validating/invalidating password confirmation_? What's the flow?

Comment: If the fields _Password_ and _Confirm Password_ do not match, there is _no_ validation error message.

Comment: @RazvanZamfir I have updated my answer so that scenario is taken into account. The code has become a bit cluttered, so you might want to do some refactoring :).

Comment: What with "PASSWORD_KEY", what is the meaning of "key" in the context?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir 'key' as in 'the key of the `initialFormData` object'.

Comment: The **[docs](https://www.simple-body-validator.com/available-validation-rules#confirmed)** provide a method, but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your logic revalidates **only on submit**, if you want it to revalidate on any change whatsoever to the form values then you need to **run your validator any time a change is made**.

That means anytime the ***formData*** state changes you also need to propagate changes based on this new formData to the ***errors*** state.

2. This is an use case for **reducers**, that is if you want to implement an arguably "clean" solution at the expense of a bit more complexity.

But the easiest, most straight forward way to achieve this result with minimal changes to your logic would be to move your validation logic in an effect ran when formData changes, such as:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import FormCard from '../components/FormCard/FormCard';
import { make } from 'simple-body-validator';

export default function Register() {

  const initialFormData = { firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '', password: '', passwordConfirm: '' };

  const validationRules = {
    firstName: ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
    lastName: ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
    email: ['required', 'email'],
    password: ['required', 'confirmed'],
    passwordConfirm: ['required'],
  };

  const validator = make(initialFormData, validationRules);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialFormData);
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, [name]: value }));
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    if (!validator.setData(formData).validate()) {
      setErrors(validator.errors());
    }
  }, [formData]);

  return (...)
}
```

Note how i removed your handleSubmit function, we don't need it anymore since the effect will run anytime the input changes anyway, which will happen before any submit does.

Comment: I tried that and the form has errors on it from the very beginning. Not what I want. :(

Comment: simply remove the initial state for errors to be an empty object. You're validating "nothing" which is gonna be an error under your validation rules, validate only when a change happens. I've updated my answer accordingly, missed this the first time :p

Comment: It does not work. There is no Angular-like instant feedback.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/crazyobject/react-validation-formik-yup

I usually do this using formik and yup.check above repo for code and below is the link for stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/validation-react-form-yup-formik?file=src%2FApp.js

Basically we need to handle below two events
Onchange
Onblur

Comment: I use Simple Body Validator.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation already explains how to handle instant validation with react (https://www.simple-body-validator.com/react/validation-quickstart#form-instant-validation-example). You just need to add two extra lines of code to the **handleChange** function:

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
  const { name, value } = event.target;
  setFormData((prevFormData) => ({ ...prevFormData, [name]: value }));

  validator.validate(name, value);
  setErrors(validator.errors());
};
```

As you saw in the code above you can instruct the library to validate the value of the specific field name on each change

Finally, you need to put the following code outside the **Register** function scope:

```
const validator = make(initialData, rules);
```

You can check the final version of the code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-poincare-xwzlxj?file=/src/pages/Register.jsx)